# How can I dynamically ensureIndex on a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data field in my schema that is of mixed payload type

```
data : {
  type : Schema.Types.Mixed
}
```

the mixed payload will be in the form of

```
"attributes" : {
            "type" : "Lead",
        },
"Email" : "test1400159913304@example1400159913304.com",
"Name" : "Test1400159913304",
"Id" : "00Qi000000OIFVeEAP"
    }
```

The payload will obviously change but I want to be able to dynamically set indexes on certain keys. 
i.e everything except attributes and Id

I will have a handle on the keys that need to be indexed.

Is there a way to dynamically index keys using either mongoose or mongo as I save the documents?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could write it pretty easily yourself by scanning your objects as they are saved and doing a createIndex call.

However I would be extremely cautious of this approach because indexes add overhead to mongo and eventually overusing indexes can start crippling your insert performance because for each insert you perform mongo needs to figure out which "bucket" the data has to go into in order to correctly use the indexes that are created.

Identify which columns you really need indexes on that you are using for your queries and stick with them.